How to Sort WordPress Posts by Custom Meta Field and Date Simultaneously?
I'm currently working on a WordPress project where I need to display posts with a specific order. My goal is to show not_premium_post posts first, followed by premium_post posts. Additionally, I want all posts to be sorted by date within these categories.
Here is the code I have so far:
$query_args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'meta_query'     => array(
        'relation'     => 'OR',
        'premium_post' => array(
            'key'     => '_premium_post',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        ),
        'not_premium_post' => array(
            'key'     => '_premium_post',
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
        ),
    ),
    'orderby' => array(
        'meta_value' => 'ASC',
        'date'       => 'DESC',
    ),
    'meta_key' => '_premium_post',
);

The problem I'm encountering is that the posts are not being sorted by date. I need the not_premium_post posts to appear first, followed by the premium_post posts, and all posts should be sorted by date within these categories.
I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to adjust my query to achieve this sorting order. Thank you in advance for your help!
